# "Unexplainable" vs "Inexplicable"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, adjectives

What is the difference between *unexplainable* and *inexplicable*?  Are they exact synonyms or are there situations where one is preferred over the other?

Is *unexplainable* a clumsy modern variant (perhaps only existing due to uneducated usage) or an old word that's fallen out of fashion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Google N-gram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inexplicable%2Cunexplainable&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) suggests that *unexplainable* is a recent invention (at least in written form):

[image]

Comment: way to pull out the n-gram viewer!

Comment: An NGram of *"he inexplicably [did sth]"* against *unexplainably*, shows we simply don't use that second form. Curious, really, given that *explain* is far more common than *explicate* overall.

Answer (score 4):

The OED gives the meaning of 'unexplainable' as 'inexplicable'. The oldest citation is dated early eighteenth century, so it's not particularly new and the three citations provided don't suggest it's an uneducated usage.

Answer (score -2):

'Unexplainable' is an American  word  and yet another bastardized  version of English (-:
Inexplicable  is correct.... and I am a Louisville, Kentucky born and raised 'Yank'.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @LaNell. You make three assertions and a personal remark. Can you support the assertions with explanations or references? To write stronger answers see the [help].